# Dense linear orderings isomorphism

Tags: model-theory, order-theory

First of all the definition: A dense linear order is a $\{<\}$-structure in which the following formulas are valid:

[image]

Question: How can I prove that any two countable DLO's (dense linear order) are isomorph?

Hint (from my logic book): Let $M$ and $N$ be two countable DLOs. Now we should somehow be able to proof that every partial finite isomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ (what is the definition for a partial iso.?) can be continued to a finite partial isomorphism $f':M\rightarrow N$ which contains a given element from $M$ (or $N$) in the domain (range). Using this we can make enumerations from $M$ and $N$ and construct an isomorphism.

Comment: I think by finite partial he means you only take a finite subset in the domain and map it to a finite subset of the codomain. Far from being sure though.

Comment: Your question has an obvious and immediate answer. We can't. $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ are both DLO, but cannot be isomorphic because there is no bijection between the two sets. If you restrict your question to countable sets, then it is possible and I am almost certain that there is an answer on this site already.

Comment: I edited it, I meant countable DLOs. I found nothing on this site, I only found a proof in the book "Linear orderings" from Joseph Rosenstein, Theorem 2.8: "http://books.google.at/books?id=y3YpdW-sbFsC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=dense+linear+order+isomorphism&source=bl&ots=eQGAMAJVGM&sig=DqHJln66h2Ye957Rm_nWJT7DHhw&hl=de&sa=X&ei=2dFtUbH8N8SQ7Aah4oHIBw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=dense%20linear%20order%20isomorphism&f=false" but I do not understand it in relation to my hint. The other problem is that unfortunately the notation in logic is not uniform

Comment: You can find an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156145/dense-linear-orders-dlo/). And although it proves that DLO+endpoints are isomorphic I am certain that you will be able to figure out a way of deriving the wanted result for the case without endpoints. (I am still convinced that the answer appears somewhere on the site, though).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, still I would be really thankful if somebody could explain the proof  using the hint I stated.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the hint first recall that a partial isomorphism is a function from a subset of $M$ to a subset of $N$ which is an isomorphism of the induced substructres; i.e. bijective and order-isomorphism.

Now to show that you can always extend by one more step, suppose that $f$ was a partial isomorphism between two finite subsets, $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in M$ and $y_1\ldots y_k\in N$, such that $f(x_i)=y_i$. We may assume that $x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_k$.

Let $x\in M$ be a point distinct of all the $x_i$. If $x_k<x$ then we simply find $y\in N$ such that $y_k<y$ (since the orders are dense and without endpoints we can do that), and define $f'=f\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle\}$. Easily this is a partial isomorphism; and similarly if $x<x_1$ we find $y<y_1$ and do the same.

Otherwise there is some $i<k$ such that $x_i<x<x_{i+1}$. Since the order on $N$ is dense there is some $y\in N$ such that $y_i<y<y_{i+1}$. Simply extend $f$ to $f'$ as before, by setting $f'(x)=y$ and $f'(x_i)=y_i$.

In all cases it is easily checked that the result is a partial isomorphism. The proof of extending the function by a point from $N$ is the same by noting that $f^{-1}$ is a partial isomorphism in the other direction (so now we again extend the domain).

---

Now you fix some enumeration of the two DLOs and simply set $f_0(x_0)=y_0$; and then continue by induction each time carefully adding a point from the domain and then a point from the range.

Comment: Thank you, one questions. What do you mean with the notation $\{<(x,y)>\}$ ?

Comment: @Voyage: It means that I have to go to bed... :-)

Comment: Hi Asaf, I'm a little puzzled with $f$ finally being a full isomorphism (would all partial finite isomorphisms finally imply the full isomorphism also?)  - how are we ensuring this is the case? In other proofs, I've seen that this is ensured when during construction, we choose the least indexed $i$ that puts the newly extended image element in the same relative position as the new domain element. However, I also don't see how this guarantees the final map is an isomorphism - wondering if you could clarify on that method or for the isomorphism part in your answer?

Comment: @CowNorris: Yes, that's the "carefully" part in that last sentence.

Comment: I'm having trouble convincing myself that being "careful" this way actually will work - wondering if you could clarify a little more?

Comment: @CowNorris: The point is that you extend one step at a time, and each time you take the least index that wasn't used. If the function is not defined on the whole domain, then there is a least point where you could have chosen that indexed element, but you haven't. So why? Well, because you had used it before. So indeed this is defined everywhere, and the same argument shows that it's also surjective.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you very much for spelling it out! I couldn't see that line of logic for the life of me.