# Order-preserving isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Suppose we have a linearly ordered group over $\mathbb Z^n$ where the ordering goes left-to-right, i.e. when deciding if $(x_1,x_2,\dots)<(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ we first check if $x_1< y_1$, if it is then $X< Y$. If they are the same, we compare $x_2< y_2$ and so on.

I believe there is an isomorphism to a subset of $\mathbb Q$ which preserves this ordering. Namely, a Godel numbering $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto 2^{x_1}3^{x_2}\dots$ is an isomorphism which  has the same ordering if we first use the 2-adic norm, then the 3-adic norm etc.

I think a slightly more convoluted isomorphism exists even if we're dealing with $\mathbb Q^n$. However, I'm not sure if this is true if we're dealing with $\mathbb R^n$. So I ask:

> For any group over $\mathbb R^n$ which uses the left-to-right ordering, is there an equivalent group over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: If you're interested in how to prove the result I mention in my answer (re: dense linear orders), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156145/dense-linear-orders-dlo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Note that an order-isomorphism will be an injective continuous function when both are considered in the order topology. Consider then $\Bbb R^2$ ordered as you describe, and in particular consider the images of the connected sets $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ of $\Bbb R^2$ under any continuous function. The continuous image of a connected set is connected, so for $f$ to be injective, we will require for the images of those connected sets to be disjoint, uncountable connected subsets of $\Bbb R$. The interiors of these connected sets would be disjoint open intervals or rays, but there would be uncountably many of these, which is impossible, since $\Bbb R$ has a countable dense subset.

Incidentally, I'm not sure what your rational isomorphism is supposed to do, but I don't think it works. However, as a countable dense linear order with no endpoints, $\Bbb Q^n$ is order isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ as a linearly ordered *set*.  They are not isomorphic as linearly ordered *groups*: my answer works to show this as well.  (I confess I don't understand this part of the OP's question well enough to know how relevant this remark is to him.)

Comment: Is this set ($\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}$) connected, in the mentioned order topology)???

Comment: @Fagner: Yes, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @CameronBuie: OK, you actually said, and now I realize that this set is an interval wrt lexicographic order, so it's connected. On the reality i´m trying to prove that every linear order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that refines the usual product order is not order isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

An ordered abelian group $(G,+,<)$ is **Archimedean** if for all $x,y \in G$ with $x > 0$,
there is a positive integer $n$ with $nx > y$.

Famously the ordered group $(\mathbb{R},+,<)$ is Archimedean.  But for $N > 1$, $\mathbb{R}^N$ endowed with the lexicographic ordering is not: for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $n (0,1,0,\ldots,0) < (1,0,\ldots,0)$.  So they cannot be order isomorphic.

It is a theorem of Holder that an ordered abelian group is Archimedean iff it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$: see $\S$ 17.2 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf) for a proof.

These ideas can be pushed much further: a subgroup $H$ of an ordered abelian group $(G,+,<)$ is **convex** if for all $x < y< z \in G$, if $x,z \in H$ then also $y \in H$.

The family of convex subgroups of an ordered abelian group is linearly ordered under inclusion (Proposition 17.10 of [*loc. cit.*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)).  So the order isomorphism type of this set is an invariant of $(G,+,<)$, say $r(G)$.  When $r(G)$ is finite we identify it with a natural number and call it the **rank** of $G$.  Then:

$\bullet$ An ordered group has rank at most $1$ iff it is Archimedean (Proposition 17.11 of [*loc. cit.*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)).

$\bullet$ The rank of $\mathbb{R}^N$ is $N$.  (Exercise!  This refines the current question.)